# Laravel using Vagrant homestead etc/hosts not routing

Tags: php, laravel, macos, homestead

Scenario:
Host machine is mac, updated to the latest Mojave OS.
VirtualBox installed to run VM's.

Generated the homestead folder, and my Homestead.yaml file is as follows:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
folders:
    - map: ~/Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel
sites:
    - map: website.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/website/public
databases:
    - homestead
```

I have a folder on my mac that has been mapped to the folder in the VM. The mapping is fine as I can delete/create files in the VM.

My /etc/hosts file contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   website.test
```

The website.test routes to a simple index page in Laravel.

When I navigate to http://website.test in Safari and Chrome, nothing happens.
I've flushed my DNS; provisioned my VM; destroyed and rebuilt my VM; still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So this is your /etc/hosts file on your Mac? Not inside the VM? If you open a Terminal and `ping website.test`, do it show that it's trying to ping `192.168.10.10`? What does "nothing happens" mean exactly? The web browsers should return some sort of error if they can't resolve the address or if they can resolve the address but cannot connect etc.

Comment: Do `homestead reload --provision` to apply new settings into box.